# Softmax gives odd results

Tags: python, python-3.x, softmax

If I run this:

```
probs = np.array( [683.8336792, 861.69769287, 981.83361816, 834.32391357] )
softs = softmax([probs])[0]
print(softs)
```

softs is always skewed massively to the largest 981.83 number - any idea why?

```
[3.80426623e-130 6.69315016e-053 1.00000000e+000 8.65663825e-065]
```

softmax function is from sklearn package

```
def softmax(X, copy=True):

    if copy:
        X = np.copy(X)
    max_prob = np.max(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
    X -= max_prob
    np.exp(X, X)
    sum_prob = np.sum(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
    X /= sum_prob
    return X
```

Comment: Those are the correct values (at least, to within numerical constraints). That's what softmax does. Why do you think the results are odd? For example, the second and third entries differ by ~120.1, so the softmax values differ by a factor of around exp(-120.1) = 6.7e-53.

Comment: If you want a more diverse spread, consider scaling your data down by multiplying your inputs by a number in (0,1)

Comment: Your result is correct. Try to sum the result, you'll get *1*... :-)

Comment: Voting to migrate this question to stats.SO, as the programming is fine - asker seems to want advice on how to calibrate the methods here.

Comment: Yes, migrating to stats might not be a bad move, as if I take a factor of 100 out then it gives more the results I'd expect to get: [0.03214058 0.19033002 0.63277744 0.14475197]  Not sure why original numbers would give different result...